# Pass directory path to release tfs 2017.1

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to send to tfs release management a path to release without build being triggered.( I trigger a release from code).

I tried to give a new sourceBranch path and even defaultworkingdirectory...

what is the the variable that I need to pass to tfs to make it work? and what variable should I use at the release?

Thank

Comment: What **doesn't** work?

Comment: I don't know how to copy the artifacts from the path that I'm sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger a release with the specific build as the artifacts source, you just need to use the [create release REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#create-a-release) to specify the corresponding build ID.

So, in you code you can try using the variable **Build.BuildId** to get the build ID first then use create release REST API to trigger the release.

```
POST http://win-ke1habi:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/LCTFVCScrum/_apis/release/releases/?api-version=3.0-preview.2

Content-Type: application/json

{
  "definitionId": {release definition id},
  "description": "lctest 0627 07 07 ",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "{build definition name-alias}",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "{build id}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you set the TFVC **Repository** as the artifacts source in your release definition, you just need to specify the source version (changeset version) to trigger the release:

```
POST http://win-ke1habi:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/LCTFVCScrum/_apis/release/releases/?api-version=3.0-preview.2

Content-Type: application/json

{
    "definitionId": 4,
    "description": "test060727",
    "artifacts": [
        {
               "alias": "LCTFVCScrum",
                 "instanceReference": {
                        "name": "Changeset 38",
                        "id": "38",
                        "sourceBranch": "$/LCTFVCScrum"
                 }
        }       
    ]
}
```

**Update:**

It's impossible if you want to use variable without TFS system, according to your description, the patch system is a individual system, the variable cannot be identified within the release process even if you set it.

If you want to do that automatically, you have to use TFS system, eg: For patches , crate CI build, check in the incremental patch will trigger the build definition to generate the Artifacts (The build number would be the patch number) , then create a CD release set the CI build definition as the Artifacts Source.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand from your answer - assuming that my build Id is 2. I will send json that looked this '"definitionid":2,"description":"bla bla" and my release will start. What is the field that I need to send to make the release copy the path content?

Comment: Thank you. If I want to copy a folder that is not from tfs, it's possible?

Comment: @EladMotola You can create a copy command file(cmd file), check in cmd file, then add a "Batch Script" task in build or release definition, then run the cmd with Batch Script task. Copy folder command sample : (XCOPY \\server\DirA\0626\* \\server\DirA\0628 /s /i) , See https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

Comment: i will explain the situation, i built a patch system for my company, and i want to send patch for the release. its not the same directory every time -  for example, i will have C:\Patches\159 and the week after i will have C:\Paches\160 (assum that the number is patch number).

Comment: @EladMotola So you can use the copy command within the release definition, but if you want to achieve that automatically every time, you have to set a variable that available within the release process for the patch number grow incrementally, then use it in the copy command, otherwise you have to specify the path manually every time.

Comment: "you have to set a variable that available within the release process for the patch number grow incrementally" - how can I do it?

Comment: @EladMotola It's not possible, according to your description, the patch system is a individual system, the variable cannot be identified within the release process even if you set it. If you want to do that automatically, you have to use TFS system, eg: For patches , crate CI build, check in the incremental patch will trigger the build definition to generate the Artifacts (The build number would be the patch number) , then create a CD release set the CI build definition as the Artifacts Source.